# Examples of Non-Markov process with continuous time and finite set of states.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

What is the best real world examples of **non**-Markov process with continuous time, but with finite set of states?

Comment: "Best", for which criterion?

Comment: Well, for example, particle motion in  thick liquid is a non-Markov process with continuous state set. That's a good example that is omnipresend and imaginable.